# Deep copy of "xml_document" in pugixml "Clone"

Tags: pugixml

I'm using pugixml library to read and write xml files.

How can I do deep copy "Clone" to the xml_document object in pugixml library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the easiest option:

```
xml_document copy;
copy.reset(doc);
```

If you need to be more fine-grained you can use `copy.append_copy()` on individual nodes.